# Import error when Python and package have same name

Tags: python

I have a package called `mango`, containing `mango.py` as follows:

```
class Mango:
    def __init__(self):
        print("mango object")
```

as well as `test_mango.py`, as follows:

```
from mango.mango import Mango
m = Mango()
```

When I run test_mango.py, I get this error:

```
    from mango.mango import Mango
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mango.mango'; 'mango' is not a package
```

If I change `mango.py`'s filename to `mango_main.py` and import, it works. Why does the error with `mango.mango` occur?

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` inside the mango dir?

Comment: because you are already inside the `mango` dir. Either make sure the working dir is outside of the `mango` dir, use a different file name for `mango.py` or change the import to `from mango import Mango`

Comment: Hi deepSpace,, May I know if it is python rule that module name and package name shouldn't be the same? or, there is no such rule but it is python's import rule?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to change your code to:

```
from mango import Mango
```

as [DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace) suggested.